# How to retain my dropdown design after dropdown cascading in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have problem with my dropdownlist design when i select the first dropdownlist the second dropdownlist will refresh but the design has been change

[image]

After I select a value from the country dropdownlist, a province dropdown design may suddenly change:

[image]

Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Country</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryNames, Model.CountryNames, "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlState", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Province</label>
    <div id="Province">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProvinceNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlProvince", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my script function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlState').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/ContactAddress/GetProvince",
            data: { stateId: $('#ddlState').val() },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var district = "<select id='ddlProvince'>";
                district = district + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    district = district + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                }
                district = district + '</select>';
                $('#Province').html(district);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I change my code instead of .html i used append but my Province dll no data shows

```
        $('#ddlState').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/ContactAddress/GetProvince",
                data: { stateId: $('#ddlState').val() },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var district = "<select id='ddlProvince'>";
                    district = district + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        district = district + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    }
                    district = district + '</select>';
                    $('#dllProvince').append(district);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely removing the dropdown from the html tree and rebuilding it by adding html to your div. Better way would be to remove the current options like

```
    $('#ddlProvince')
    .empty();
```

and then append the options. Your function should look like this.

```
    success: function (data) {
            var district = "";
            $('#ddlProvince').append('<option value="">--Select--</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#ddlProvince').append('<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>');
            }


        }
```

Comment: I try your suggestion but no value shows in my dllProvince

Comment: it should be $('#Province') but still same result

Comment: remove <select> opening and closing tags

Answer (score 0):

this one working for me thank you for giving solution

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlState').change(function () {
            $('#ddlProvince').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/ContactAddress/GetProvince",
                data: { stateId: $('#ddlState').val() },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var district = "<select id='ddlProvince'>";
                    district = district + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('#ddlProvince').append('<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```